# how do i backup hbase using distcp?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I would like to do a back up of hbase files using distcp.  Then point hbase to the newly copied files and work with the stored tables.

I realize that there are tools out there which are recommended for this job.  However, I'd like to know what I need to do after I've copied the files to get hbase to recognize the copied files.

For example, i'd like to start hbase shell and scan the stored tables from the newly copied file.

Answer (score 2):

DistCp (distributed copy) is a tool used for large inter/intra-cluster copying. So if you want to backup your clusterA to clusterB, you'll have to:

- do the copy from clusterA to clusterB using distcp
- start an Hbase master and some RegionServers
- enjoy the command line interface on clusterB

This means have 2 clusters each with HDFS and Hbase.

**But**, if you want to backup your data in the **same** cluster, this is simplier:

- do the intra copy in a different folder: hadoop distcp hdfs://nn:8020/hbase hdfs://nn:8020/backuptest
- stop all the Hbase processes and change the property hbase.rootdir from "hbase" to "backuptest"
- restart all the processes

Comment: I want to gradually copy tables, one by one to the new cluster. Is there a way to "load" table (after distcp) without restarting master / region-servers?

Comment: @ItayB yes, you don't need to restart hadoop to restore table from snapshot. Just use `restore_snapshot` or `clone_snapshot ` command. 
https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.0/hbase-data-access/content/restore-snapshot.html
https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.0/hbase-data-access/content/clone-a-table-from-snapshot.html